# Customizing Spring concurrent-session-control configuration

Tags: spring

How do I detect and inform the user that they already have an active session and provide them an option to create a new session or close the current active one? Please advise. Thanks much.

Answer (score -1):

you could use the following configuration in your spring security-context.xml

1. in your security-context.xml